# Published hosted Blazor wasm app only shows Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I would like to publish a hosted Blazor WASM application and run the generated .exe locally for test purposes. To do this with the standard blazorwasm template I have tried the following steps:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Then I have started the generated server .exe file. When I now open http://localhost:5001 in the browser it just displays "Loading...", but never loads the blazor application. There is also no console output from the server. Did I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Did you run the server or the client project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check the website, you can see that, the `framework/blazor.webassembly.js` doesn't load successfully:

[image]

> ```
> dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted
> ```

The issue is relats that, by using the above command, it will create a multiple Blazor WebAssembly app, the solution contains three projects, like this:

[image]

Then, if you use `dotnet publish -c Release` to publish the web apps, the published file will be located in the `/bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/publish/wwwroot` folder (In the Blazor.client and Blazor.Server projects). Then, if you run the `Blazor.Server.exe` file, the Content root path is Server folder, and the `blazor.webassembly.js` file is in the Client folder, so it causes the `blazor.webassembly.js` file doesn't load successfully. Like this:

[image]

To solve this issue, you could try to assign an output directory when publish the web apps:

For example: In the `E:\Temp\Blazor` folder, I'm using the following command to create web apps, and publish the web app to the Publish folder.

```
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted
dotnet publish -c Release -o E:\Temp\Blazor\Publish
```

After that, in the Publish folder, it contains all published files. Running the `Blazor.Server.exe`, the output as below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Run the 'dotnet publish -c Release' on the /Server folder.

Running it at the solution level does not produce the wasm files in the publish folder, or they are somehow cleared out...

Solution Publish

```
PS C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor> dotnet publish -c Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Blazor.Shared -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Shared\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Shared.dll
  Blazor.Shared -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Shared\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\
  Blazor.Client -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Client\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Client.dll
  Blazor.Client (Blazor output) -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Client\bin\Release\net5.0\wwwroot
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
  Blazor.Client -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Client\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\
  Blazor.Server -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Server.dll
  Blazor.Server -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Server.Views.dll
  Blazor.Server -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\
```

Server Project Publish

```
PS C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server> dotnet publish -c Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Blazor.Shared -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Shared\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Shared.dll
  Blazor.Client -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Client\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Client.dll
  Blazor.Client (Blazor output) -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Client\bin\Release\net5.0\wwwroot
  Blazor.Server -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Server.dll
  Blazor.Server -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\Blazor.Server.Views.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
  Blazor.Server -> C:\Users\u0\Desktop\Blazor\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\
```